# issue with loading multiple overlays using z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a webpage where when an ajax call takes place, I load an overlay until the call is over.

The css for the overlay is:

```
.ajax-loading{
    position:   absolute;
    z-index:    1001;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .9 )
                url('/images/loading.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;              
}
```

And to show this I have `<div id='loader'></div>` to which I attach this class as `$('#loader').addClass('ajax-loading');` and I `removeClass()` once loading is complete. This works perfectly without any problems.

The problem started when I added another overlay for detail product view. This overlay is activated when someone clicks on product details link. The CSS for this overlay is:

```
.product-detail {  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color: black;
}
```

From this overlay, there are buttons which will make ajax calls. If I try to load the ajax-loading overlay on the click of buttons that are in product details, then the ajax-loading layer is displayed below the product-detail layer. How can I modify this behavior so that the ajax-loading overlay is shown on top of the product detail layer?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `.ajax-loading { position: fixed; }`. If you can't do that for some reason, try removing `z-index: 1000` from your `.product-detail` rule.

Comment: Hey @Jonathan! And Undefined Variable, can you please post a link to an example? The code *seems* correct (at first glance) to me...

Comment: @Jonathan you had me so confused there for a minute.

Comment: @Jonathan And vice versa.

Comment: @Jonathan sorry, had to change my display name. This was too much. There can only be one.

Comment: This confusion was funny xD Also, @UndefinedVariable I think there's something else in your code that's messing with you. I tried to replicate it and I couldn't https://jsfiddle.net/dh6y1yjc/

Comment: @Piyin: can you check the fiddle? I see black background...

Comment: @jperezov: let me try doing position:fixed

Comment: @jperezov: unfortunately that does not solve the problem :(

Comment: @UndefinedVariable It must be something on your browser then, I see white with "Loader" written, in Chrome, Opera and Firefox

Comment: @Piyin: yeah, I did a hard refresh and see it now...like everyone stated here, seems like the code is correct but something related to my html maybe...unfortunately I cannot post it here because it is a jungle with a lot of legacy stuff. I will dig more..thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @UndefinedVariable Ok, no problem, at least you solved it :) Have a nice day

Comment: Just a thought:) Is #loader inside .product-element or these are siblings?